# Read a string of 1's and 0's. Count numbers of successive 1's and number of successive 0's, until the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Read a string of 1's and 0's. Count numbers of successive 1's 
and number of successive 0's, 
until the end.

For example,

```
s = "10001110000111"
```

Output should be:

```
1 1's
3 0's
3 1's
4 0's
3 1's
```

I need help approaching this using only string functions (no find function), and while/for loops.

I have this:

```
myString = input("Please enter a string of 0s and 1s: ")
zeroCount = 0
oneCount = 0
index = 0

while index < (len(myString) -1):
    if myString[index] == "0":
        zeroCount += 1
        if myString[index +1] == "1":
            zeroCount = 0
    elif myString[index] == "1":
        oneCount += 1
        if myString[index +1] == "0":
            oneCount = 0
    index += 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite similar to what's called 'run length encoding' which has a nice entry on [Rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Python)

```
def encode(input_string):
    count = 1
    prev = ''
    lst = []
    for character in input_string:
        if character != prev:
            if prev:
                entry = (prev,count)
                lst.append(entry)
                #print lst
            count = 1
            prev = character
        else:
            count += 1
    else:
        entry = (character,count)
        lst.append(entry)
    return lst


def decode(lst):
    q = ""
    for character, count in lst:
        q += character * count
    return q

#Method call
encode("aaaaahhhhhhmmmmmmmuiiiiiiiaaaaaa")
decode([('a', 5), ('h', 6), ('m', 7), ('u', 1), ('i', 7), ('a', 6)])
```

I think you'll be able to take this and modify it a bit to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to step away from pure language techniques and use a more idiomatic style, this is a wonderful time to use `groupby` which takes an input and splits it into groups based on when a key function returns a different value. In this case the key function is just the value, so we can omit it.

```
import itertools

s = "10001110000111"
groups = itertools.groupby(s)
```

`groups` is now a `groupby` iterator that lazily evaluates to:

```
[('1', ['1']),
 ('0', ['0', '0', '0']),
 ('1', ['1', '1', '1']),
 ('0', ['0', '0', '0', '0']),
 ('1', ['1', '1', '1'])]
```

You can iterate over this to see:

```
for groupname, group in groups:
    length = sum(1 for _ in group)
    # group is not a list, it just acts like one, so we can't use len
    print("{} {}'s".format(length, groupname))
```

All together, it looks like:

```
import itertools

s = "10001110000111"
groups = itertools.groupby(s)

for groupname, group in groups:
    length = sum(1 for _ in group)
    print("{} {}'s".format(length, groupname))
```

and returns a result of

```
1 1's
3 0's
3 1's
4 0's
3 1's
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` method of string to find next sequence and trim source string in each step:

```
s = "10001110000111"

while s:
    try:
        count = s.index("0") if s[0] == "1" else s.index("1")
        print("{} {}'s".format(count, s[0]))
        s = s[count:]
    except ValueError:
        print("{} {}'s".format(len(s), s[0]))
        break
```